# Make lambda non-copyable/non-movable

Tags: c++, lambda

Consider the following [code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/8jdXCYLzhqJ6ptJe):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

int main() {
    std::thread t;
    const auto l = [x = std::move(t)]{};
    decltype(l) m = std::move(l);
}
```

This code doesn't compile with the following messages:

> ```
> prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
> prog.cc:7:32: error: use of deleted function 'main()::<lambda()>::<lambda>(const main()::<lambda()>&)'
>     7 |     decltype(l) m = std::move(l);
>       |                                ^
> prog.cc:6:37: note: 'main()::<lambda()>::<lambda>(const main()::<lambda()>&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
>     6 |     const auto l = [x = std::move(t)]{};
>       |                                     ^
> prog.cc:6:37: error: use of deleted function 'std::thread::thread(const std::thread&)'
> In file included from prog.cc:2:
> /opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/10.0.1/thread:154:5: note: declared here
>   154 |     thread(const thread&) = delete;
>       |     ^~~~~~
> ```

Is there a way to make lambda non-copyable or non-movable without explicit capturing an any non-copyable variable (i.e. leaving `[]` empty)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a simple enveloping aggregate that will prevent the move and copy.

```
struct NoCopyMove {
    NoCopyMove(NoCopyMove const&) = delete;
    NoCopyMove(NoCopyMove&&)      = delete;

    void operator=(NoCopyMove const&) = delete;
    void operator=(NoCopyMove&&)      = delete;
};

template<class Functor>
struct Fixed : Functor, NoCopyMove {
    using Functor::operator();
};

template<typename F>
Fixed (F&&) -> Fixed<std::decay_t<F>>;
```

To be used like this

```
const auto l = Fixed{[]{}};
```

`NoCopyMove` is a simple mixin that disables copying and moving. Writing it this way allows us to keep the specializations of `Fixed` as simple aggregates.

All `Fixed` does is inherit/initialize as base (with guaranteed copy elision when possible) the functor it's being given as an argument. And then expose its `operator()`.

Since there are no members involved (other then maybe in `Functor`), and since a lambda cannot possibly inherit from our custom `NoCopyMove` class, the empty base optimization kicks in for stateless lambdas. So objects are not expected to be any larger than the lambda you initialize them with.

Comment: Nice! It will also still allow the default construction of stateless lambdas, that C+20 introduces.

Comment: Did you check code compilation? It [doesn't compile for me](https://wandbox.org/permlink/xoGFmecCmphGVgFh). Looks like the default ctor should be added: `NoCopyMove() = default;`

Comment: And BTW `= delete;` the move members seems enough due to imcplicitly deleting the copy members as well.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - Of course I checked it. Doesn't mean my compiler couldn't have had a bug. And BTW, I prefer deleting stuff explicitly, not implicitly.

Comment: Then ... what's wrong with my attempt (link in my first comment)? Could you please share your compilable version of code?

Comment: The last two lines are new to me. Could you (or anyone else who knows) provide an explaining link?

Comment: @sweenish this is a part of [class template argument deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ - The difference is that I compiled my code as C++17 (https://wandbox.org/permlink/zcUqB4OMrbNkIL2P), while you compiled it as C++2a. Seems the initialization rules changed. I'm not sure how though at the moment. But if C++20 requires a defaulted default c'tor for `NoCopyMove`, it doesn't make much of a difference for the idiom.